# How to make a new List in Java

Tags: java, list, collections

We create a `Set` as:

```
Set myset = new HashSet()
```

How do we create a `List` in Java?

Answer (score 1169, accepted):

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

or with generics ([Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond) or later)

```
List<MyType> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

or with generics (Old java versions)

```
List<MyType> myList = new ArrayList<MyType>();
```

Comment: Note that ArrayList is not the only kind of List -- and, regarding the question, HashSet is not the only kind of Set.

Comment: I am surprised that no one has mentioned that you can look up the list interface in the Java documentation to get a definite list of all the classes that implement List: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: If you use an IDE you can also generally view a type hierarchy in there, which may be more convenient. In Eclipse the default shortcut is F4, and in IDEA it is Ctrl+H.

Comment: From what I understand you cannot use generics with ArrayList in C# [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41107z8a%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: @CodeFlava The equivalent of ArrayList<> in C# is List<>()

Comment: The second explicit type argument <MyType> can be replaced with just <> for Java 7 and 8.

Comment: In Java 9, List.of("item1","item2") is the easiest and most concise way of doing it - but beware that it creates an immutable list.

Answer (score 591):

Additionally, if you want to create a list that has things in it (though it will be fixed size):

```
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You");
```

Comment: The caveat is that this type of list (the one returned by asList()) is immutable.

Comment: @Avron - wrong: it is only fixed size: you can not change the size, but you can change the content (caveat of the caveat?)

Comment: if there's only one thing in the list, I use Collections.singletonList() instead of Arrays.asList().  (But, I guess, I don't know why.)

Comment: @MikeB if you don't know why then stick to the arrays.aslist

Comment: Because intellij said so @bharal

Answer (score 213):

Let me summarize and add something:

**[JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/)**

```
1. new ArrayList<String>();
2. Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")
```

**[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)**

```
1. Lists.newArrayList("Mike", "John", "Lesly");
2. Lists.asList("A","B", new String [] {"C", "D"});
```

**Immutable List**

```
1. Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A","B")));
2. ImmutableList.builder()                                      // Guava
            .add("A")
            .add("B").build();
3. ImmutableList.of("A", "B");                                  // Guava
4. ImmutableList.copyOf(Lists.newArrayList("A", "B", "C"));     // Guava
```

**Empty immutable List**

```
1. Collections.emptyList();
2. Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

**List of Characters**

```
1. Lists.charactersOf("String")                                 // Guava
2. Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.fixedLength(1).split("String"))  // Guava
```

**List of Integers**

```
Ints.asList(1,2,3);                                             // Guava
```

Comment: `Ints.asList` does not create an immutable list, but a fixed-size list backed by given array of ints (i.e. it supports `List.set(int, Object)`). Second example of "Immutable List of Characters" isn't immutable either (I'd remove that line).

Comment: Not using generics makes a really "good" example for any developer that will read this.

Answer (score 95):

#### In Java 8

To create a non-empty list of fixed size (operations like add, remove, etc., are not supported):

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2); // but, list.set(...) is supported
```

To create a non-empty mutable list:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 4));
```

#### In Java 9

Using a new [`List.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) static factory methods:

```
List<Integer> immutableList = List.of(1, 2);

List<Integer> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(3, 4));
```

#### In Java 10

Using the [Local Variable Type Inference](https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference.html):

```
var list1 = List.of(1, 2);

var list2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(3, 4));

var list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And follow best practices...

#### [Don't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Since Java 5, generics have been a part of the language - you should use them:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // Good, List of String

List list = new ArrayList(); // Bad, don't do that!
```

#### [Program to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

For example, program to the `List` interface:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Instead of:

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(); // This is a bad idea!
```

Answer (score 30):

First read [this](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), then read [this](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [this](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). 9 times out of 10 you'll use one of those two implementations.

In fact, just read [Sun's Guide to the Collections framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html).

Comment: I'd even add "8 times out of 10" you'll use ArrayList, just because it simply doesn't matter in 9.9 times out of 10.

Comment: LinkedList is semantically appropriate when you only really care about the ends.

Comment: LinkedLists are excellent if you just are going to iterate over them.
To mee, it seems as if  linked lists are more elegant, but maybe it's just because i learned lisp before Java.

Comment: @Karlp Agreed. I would say it's about 50/50 most of the time between ArrayList and LinkedList, and the answer isn't always about the complexity of the operations; more often it's simply what feels right for the problem at hand.

Comment: I almost always used `ArrayList`. If I'm only working with the the ends of a list, it's a deque (or queue) and I use the `ArrayDeque` implementation. The reason is that even though the array-based implementations *might* waste some memory on empty slots (when I can't predict the necessary capacity), for small collections this is is comparable to the overhead of all the node instances in a linked list (or deque). And in return, I get random access. What unique benefit does `LinkedList` provide?

Answer (score 23):

Since Java 7 you have [type inference for generic instance creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html), so there is no need to duplicate generic parameters on the right hand side of the assignment:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

A fixed-size list can be defined as:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
```

For immutable lists you can use the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) library:

```
List<String> list = ImmutableList.of("foo", "bar");
```

Comment: I have a question regarding this declaration List<String> list = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"); 

I am wondering whether list in the declaration is an object ?

Answer (score 21):

```
//simple example creating a list form a string array

String[] myStrings = new String[] {"Elem1","Elem2","Elem3","Elem4","Elem5"};

List mylist = Arrays.asList(myStrings );

//getting an iterator object to browse list items

Iterator itr= mylist.iterator();

System.out.println("Displaying List Elements,");

while(itr.hasNext())

  System.out.println(itr.next());
```

Answer (score 21):

`List` is an interface like `Set` and has `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` as [general purpose implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html).

We can create List as:

```
 List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
```

We can also create a fixed-size list as:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
```

We would almost always be using `ArrayList` opposed to `LinkedList` implementation:

1. `LinkedList` uses a lot of space for objects and performs badly when we have lots of elements.
2. Any indexed operation in `LinkedList` requires O(n) time compared to O(1) in `ArrayList`.
3. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist) for more information.

The list created by `Arrays.asList` above can not be modified structurally but its elements can still be modified.

### Java 8

As per [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-), the method `Collections.unmodifiableList` returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. We can get it like:

```
Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
```

### Java 9

In case we are using **Java 9** then:

```
List<String> list = List.of("A", "B");
```

### Java 10

In case we are at Java 10 then the method `Collectors.unmodifiableList` will return an instance of truly unmodifiable list introduced in Java 9. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52536126/1216775) for more info about the difference in `Collections.unmodifiableList`  vs `Collectors.unmodifiableList` in **Java 10**.

Answer (score 20):

[List](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is just an interface just as [Set](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Like HashSet is an implementation of a Set which has certain properties in regards to add / lookup / remove performance, ArrayList is the bare implementation of a List.

If you have a look at the documentation for the respective interfaces you will find "All Known Implementing Classes" and you can decide which one is more suitable for your needs.

Chances are that it's [ArrayList](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 13):

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

Or with generics

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You can, of course, replace string with any type of variable, such as Integer, also.

Answer (score 13):

The following are some ways you can create lists.

- This will create a list with fixed size, *adding/removing* elements is not possible, it will throw a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` if you try to do so.

```
    List<String> fixedSizeList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Male", "Female"});
    List<String> fixedSizeList = Arrays.asList("Male", "Female");
    List<String> fixedSizeList = List.of("Male", "Female"); //from java9
```

- The following version is a simple list where you can add/remove any number of elements.

  ```
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  ```

- This is how to create a `LinkedList` in java, If you need to do frequent insertion/deletion of elements on the list, you should use `LinkedList` instead of `ArrayList`

  ```
   List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
  ```

Comment: You can use `Arrays.asList("Male", "Female")`.

Answer (score 10):

As declaration of array list in java is like

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, Serializable
```

There is numerous way you can create and initialize array list in java.

```
 1) List list = new ArrayList();

 2) List<type> myList = new ArrayList<>();

 3) List<type> myList = new ArrayList<type>();

 4) Using Utility class

    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(8, 4);
    Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));

 5) Using static factory method

    List<Integer> immutableList = List.of(1, 2);


 6) Creation and initializing at a time

    List<String> fixedSizeList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Male", "Female"});



 Again you can create different types of list. All has their own characteristics

 List a = new ArrayList();
 List b = new LinkedList();
 List c = new Vector(); 
 List d = new Stack(); 
 List e = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();
```

Answer (score 9):

One example:

```
List somelist = new ArrayList();
```

You can look at the [javadoc for List](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and find all known implementing classes of the `List` interface that are included with the java api.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes - but only very rarely - instead of a new ArrayList, you may want a new LinkedList.  Start out with ArrayList and if you have performance problems and evidence that the list is the problem, and a lot of adding and deleting to that list - then - not before - switch to a LinkedList and see if things improve.  But in the main, stick with ArrayList and all will be fine.

Answer (score 7):

Using [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/), you could use the following methods in the [Lists](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) class

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

// ...

List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList();

List<Integer> integers = Lists.newLinkedList();
```

There are overloads for varargs initialization and initialising from an `Iterable<T>`.

The advantage of these methods is that you don't need to specify the generic parameter explicitly as you would with the constructor - the compiler will infer it from the type of the variable.

Answer (score 7):

As an option you can use double brace initialization here:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(){
  {
   add("a");
   add("b");
  }
};
```

Comment: This is an expensive operation. You are creating an anonymous subclass of ArrayList here.

Comment: @VikramBodicherla I agree. It's more about syntax sugar here.

Answer (score 7):

More options to do the same thing with Java 8, not better, not worse, just different and if you want to do some extra work with the lists, [Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) will provide you more alternatives (filter, map, reduce, etc.)

```
List<String> listA = Stream.of("a", "B", "C").collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> listB = IntStream.range(10, 20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Double> listC = DoubleStream.generate(() -> { return new Random().nextDouble(); }).limit(10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
LinkedList<Integer> listD = Stream.iterate(0, x -> x++).limit(10).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
List<Object> nameOfList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

You need to import `List` and `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 6):

With Java 9, you are able to do the following to create an **immutable** `List`:

```
List<Integer> immutableList = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

List<Integer> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(immutableList);
```

Answer (score 6):

List can be created in many ways:

**1 - Constructor Initialization**

List is an interface, and the instances of List can be created in the following ways:

```
List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> llist=new LinkedList<Integer>();
List<Integer> stack=new Stack<Integer>();
```

**2- Using Arrays.asList()**

```
List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

**3- Using Collections class methods**

***Empty List***

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

OR

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.emptyList();

Collections.addAll(list = new ArrayList<Integer>(), 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

***Unmodifiable List***

```
List<Integer> list = Collections
        .unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

***Singleton List***

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.singletonList(2);
```

You can find more way from the reference link below.

Reference:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/initializing-a-list-in-java/

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to create a Set and a List. HashSet and ArrayList are just two examples.  It is also fairly common to use generics with collections these days. I suggest you have a look at what they are

This is a good introduction for java's builtin collections. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html

Answer (score 5):

```
List arrList = new ArrayList();
```

Its better you use generics as suggested below:

```
List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();

arrList.add("one");
```

Incase you use LinkedList.

```
List<String> lnkList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) you can create a List like this:

```
List<String> list1 = Lists.mutable.empty();
List<String> list2 = Lists.mutable.of("One", "Two", "Three");
```

If you want an immutable list:

```
ImmutableList<String> list3 = Lists.immutable.empty();
ImmutableList<String> list4 = Lists.immutable.of("One", "Two", "Three");
```

You can avoid auto-boxing by using primitive lists. Here's how you'd create int lists:

```
MutableIntList list5 = IntLists.mutable.empty();
MutableIntList list6 = IntLists.mutable.of(1, 2, 3);

ImmutableIntList list7 = IntLists.immutable.empty();
ImmutableIntList list8 = IntLists.immutable.of(1, 2, 3);
```

There are variants for all 8 primitives.

```
MutableLongList longList       = LongLists.mutable.of(1L, 2L, 3L);
MutableCharList charList       = CharLists.mutable.of('a', 'b', 'c');
MutableShortList shortList     = ShortLists.mutable.of((short) 1, (short) 2, (short) 3);
MutableByteList byteList       = ByteLists.mutable.of((byte) 1, (byte) 2, (byte) 3);
MutableBooleanList booleanList = BooleanLists.mutable.of(true, false);
MutableFloatList floatList     = FloatLists.mutable.of(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
MutableDoubleList doubleList   = DoubleLists.mutable.of(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("bla1", "bla2", "bla3");
```

Or:

```
List<String> list1 = Lists.mutable.empty(); // Empty
List<String> list2 = Lists.mutable.of("One", "Two", "Three");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need a serializable, immutable list with a single entity you can use:

```
List<String> singList = Collections.singletonList("stackoverlow");
```