# Java array initialization list ending with a comma

Tags: java, c, syntax

The comma `,` items separator used in an array initialization list may end the list in C, this is mentioned in *The C Programming Language 2nd ed by Kernighan & Ritchie* .

e.g.

```
  int c[] = { 1, 2, 3, };
```

This is convenient when the list is long, and one doesn't want to have to change/check the previous line when adding items

```
  long long c[] = { 
                    22342342344,
                     4324234234,
                    12312311111,
                   };
```

However in Java I could observe two different behaviors:
In Eclipse, the ending `,` is accepted while some versions of the maven compiler plugin complain and throw a compilation error.

However, I didn't find any mention of this singularity in the *Flanagan's Java* book.

What is the official rule regarding an ending comma after the initialization items?
Is it recommended *not* to use it?

Comment: Have you seen a compilation error when using Maven? If so, what compiler were you using?

Comment: You can initialize lists in java in many ways as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71661809/7397820

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Section 10.6 of the spec explicitly says that a trailing comma is allowed (and ignored):

> A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is ignored.

[Link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.6)

Answer (score 4):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/), [section 10.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.6):

> A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Sun javac has a bug wrt parsing trailing commas in annotations.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=284088

Comment: This is the actual JDK bug report: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6337964 (fixed during Java 7's life, and backported to 6)