# array with comma and without comma

Tags: java, arrays

I was creating String array with few elements. At that time I notice that
I have put comma after first element and it’s still compile. I thought it won’t compile. Then I print the size and it says 1

```
  String args [] = {request.getParentMessageID() , };
  System.out.println(args.length);
```

So

```
String args [] = {request.getParentMessageID() , };  and String args [] = {request.getParentMessageID()};
```

both behave as same.

Could someone kindly explain why these are not different and Why it compile.

Comment: Please refer this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850203/java-array-initialization-list-ending-with-a-comma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Trailing comma` in a array initialization like that are `ignored by compiler`. Those are generally added so that later on adding something to the array, just requires adding the element without worrying about comma.

So it is allowed and is a valid syntax.
This is also listed in [`JLS - Section#10.6 (Array Initializers)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6): -

> A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array
>   initializer and is ignored.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Don't know why java decide to do so rather than giving compile error

Comment: @Sura.. I have written that in 1st paragraph. and You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

As per [Java Language Specification 10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)

An array initializer is written as a comma-separated list of expressions, enclosed by braces { and }.

A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is ignored.

I hope you are clear now.