# Java create list problems with List<Type> myList = new ArrayList<Type>();

Tags: java, list

I want to create list by doing this

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

but it's not recognized, i don't know why:

Eclipse suggest me to modify the syntax :

First eclipse consider that the type List is not generic and it removes the first String brackets

```
List myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then change the type of my List and finally i have :

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't work.

[How to make a new List in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858572/how-to-make-a-new-list-in-java)
I read this post and try again with an other type it's the same problem.

EDIT:my code look like this

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.awt.List;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

The problem was solved by changing

```
import java.awt.List;
```

to

```
import java.util.List;
```

Comment: What do you mean by not recognized? Do you have any errors? Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Are you using `java.awt.List`? You should be using `java.util.List` instead.

Comment: Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. My guess is that you're importing (or declaring) a *different* `List` type.

Comment: What is a java version that you are using?

Comment: thank you all the problem was the java.awt.List i will try to understand the difference between the both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your code look like this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```