# How can I use arrays in a loop and have multiple outputs

Tags: java, arrays

My goal is to have a program which asks for all the relevant information to create an  invoice. If the user wishes to add another product/service, the program will loop and the array will increment, so that the output will provide a description and price for all the products. When running this code i get this error when i try to add a product description:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

I hope I explained my problem clearly.

```
import cs1.Keyboard;

public class Invoice_Obj{

    // This object creates an invoice

    public void invoice(){

        char answer;
        int descnum = 1;
        int pricenum = 1;

        System.out.print("Enter invoice #\t\t: ");
        String invoicenum = Keyboard.readString(); //user inputs the invoice number

        System.out.print("Enter Date\t\t: ");
        String date = Keyboard.readString(); //user inputs the date of the invoice

        System.out.print("Who is this invoice to? : ");
        String recipient = Keyboard.readString(); //user inputs the recipient of the invoice

        do{

        System.out.print("\nDescription of service or product : ");
        String[] description = new String[descnum];
        description[descnum++] = Keyboard.readString();

        System.out.print("\nTotal price of service or product : ");
        String[] price = new String[pricenum];
        price[pricenum++] = Keyboard.readString();

        System.out.print("Add another service/product? (Y/N) : ");
        answer = Keyboard.readChar();


        }while(answer=='Y' || answer=='y');

    }

}
```

Comment: It's usually helpful to provide a stack trace in order to help debug the issue.  The exception in this case does help us understand but the stack trace helps so much more.

Comment: Besides the index errors (`description[descnum++]` and `price[pricenum++]`), you create a new array each time. Probably not what you want. Consider using an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: You define an array with only one element, then you are trying to place more than one element in it with indices which do not exist.

Comment: i sugguest u use a [List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858572/how-to-make-a-new-list-in-java) for your scenario

Comment: public class Invoice_Obj{
        // This object creates an invoice
        public void invoice(){
            char answer;
            ArrayList<String> descnumList = new ArrayList() ;
            ArrayList<String> pricenumList = new ArrayList();
            ...
            do{
   ...
             descnumList.add(Keyboard.readString());
   ...
            pricenumList.add(Keyboard.readString());
            System.out.print("Add another service/product? (Y/N) : ");
            answer = Keyboard.readChar();
            }while(answer=='Y' || answer=='y');
        }
    }

Comment: //to show your input you can use foreach
    //example
    for(String data:descnumList)
     System.out.print("Your input:"+data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Initializing `String[] description = new String[descnum];`

as per your code you have initialized `descnum = 1` so it will create array of size one and you are trying to access `description[descnum++] = Keyboard.readString();` i.e., out of bound for initialized array

try changing `description[descnum++] = Keyboard.readString();` to `description[0] = Keyboard.readString();`

or increase the size of your array