# how to change object to point on the java

Tags: java

I've been working for my final essay, building a Java program to implement a K-means algorithm, and I got stuck on this error:

> object cannot be converted to point.

And this is code where my error is

```
public void plotCluster() {
    System.out.println("[Cluster: " + id+"]");
    System.out.println("[Centroid: " + centroid + "]");
    System.out.println("[Points: \n");
    for(Point p : points) { // error
        System.out.println(p);
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

Comment: Please add your code where you declare points variable

Comment: this one ? 
`public List points;
 public Point centroid;
 public int id;`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at javaapplication1.Point.createRandomPoints(Point.java:65)
 at javaapplication1.KMeans.init(KMeans.java:40)
 at javaapplication1.KMeans.main(KMeans.java:33)
C:\Users\SISWA\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Do you declare the list with a type parameter `<` `>`?  Like `List<Point>` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858572/how-to-make-a-new-list-in-java

Comment: Greg is right, you are declaring 'points' incorrectly.

Comment: @SuryaHandika , please update your question with complete code

Comment: List<Point> myList = new ArrayList<Point>();

Comment: @Eric yeah, but just make it `List<Point> myList = new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 4):

From you comment, you mention that you declare your list like this:

```
public List points;
```

and I'll assume that later, you do:

```
points = new ArrayList();
```

A `List` is a generic class, and the type parameter says what type of object the list holds.  If you don't specify the type parameter, it defaults to `Object`.

You should declare your list with the type parameter:

```
public List<Point> points;

points = new ArrayList<>();           // note the <>
```

In your current code, you've got a *raw* list (defaulting to holding `Object`), and that's why `for(Point p : points)` fails to type check.  As far as the compiler is concerned, the list holds `Object` and thus you cannot assigned it to `p` which has type `Point`.

Comment: Darn! I was in the middle of my answer when I got sidetracked! I was going to say the same thing. Oh well.  Nice answer! (+1)