# Why my search box does not work in android app map activity?

Tags: android

```
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            String location = searchView.getQuery().toString();
            List<Address> addressList = null;

            if (location != null || !location.equals("")){
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Home.this);
                try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location,1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12));
            }
```

Why I get `NullPointerException` error from line `Address address = addressList.get(0)`. I try to create searchbar in maps activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a method on `null`. Try initializing `addresslist` with an empty list or check first if `addresslist` is not null, before accessing any methods.

```
List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<Address>;
```

See: [How to make a new List in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858572/how-to-make-a-new-list-in-java) and [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)